# New field is not accessible via Powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio, error, custom-list, spfield

I have a list "Orders" in SP, where I have some data. The list definition and instance were previously created in Visual Studio and then successfully deployed.

Today I've opened VS again and added new choice field "OrderType" to `schema.xml` file. Also I've added this field to all views. Now, I can see it on list view pages, I can successfully set this field from codebehind when I adding new item:

```
SPListItem item = SPContext.Current.List.AddItem();
item["Title"] = "MyNewTitle";
item["OrderType"] = "Choice1";
item.Update();
```

But, when I'm trying to access this field from Powershell, I get error:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://myweb
$list = $web.lists["Orders"]
$items = $list.items
$item = $items[0] # Item with filled fields
$item["OrderType"] # Returns nothing
$item["OrderType"] = "Choice1" # Returns error
$item.Update()
```

Error:

```
Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.
At line:1 char:7
+ $item[ <<<< "OrderType"] = "Choice1"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (OrderType:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

In fact, I even can't find the field on web:

```
$list.Fields.GetField("OrderType")
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "GetField" with "1" argument(s): "Column 'OrderType' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
At line:1 char:22
+ $list.Fields.GetField <<<< ("OrderType")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I have full access permissions for the item. I can still see this field and its data on my list view pages.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, just simply opened my "problematic" field via "List" -> "Site settings" -> "OrderType", and than pressed "OK" (I didn't do any changes). Now I can access it via Powershell. Thanks to [this post](http://sharepointtechie.blogspot.ru/2010/04/created-and-modified-field-went-missing.html) (it's about site columns but the solution is similar)!

Answer (score 1):

You can find PowerShell samples here to get/set Choice fields:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20831.sharepoint-a-complete-guide-to-getting-and-setting-fields-using-powershell.aspx#Set_and_Get_a_Choice_Field

For example, you should be able to set your field value like this:

```
$item["OrderType"] = $list.Fields["OrderType"].GetFieldValue("Choice1");            
$item.Update();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `$list.Fields["OrderType"]` returns null. It looks like it doesn't exist, and I can't find it in `$list.Fields | ft staticname` output. The main two questions are "Where is my 'OrderType' field?" and "Why I can see it in list view if it doesn't exist?".